# How to get d3.js tree layout to sort nodes alphabetically?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm experimenting with [**this**](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) example of d3.js (pasted below in its entirety) to draw a tree based on a JSON tree structure.

This code draws a nice tree, but it doesn't sort the sibling nodes in any order vertically. The data just happens to already be sorted in the [**underlying JSON object**](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json).

I want to know how I can sort these nodes vertically in Alphabetic order (A at the top, Z at the bottom, ideally case insensitive) if the underlying data is not already sorted. What do I need to change in the code below??

**START EDIT:**

I would like to do this without modifying the underlying JSON object.
One thing I tried was to add `tree.sort(d3.ascending);` right after the `d3.layout.tree()` line. But that didn't have any effect. I don't know why.

**END EDIT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    .node {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    .node text {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    </style>
    <body>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
        width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
        height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var i = 0,
        duration = 750,
        root;

    var tree = d3.layout.tree()
        .size([height, width]);

    var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.json("/mbostock/raw/4063550/flare.json", function(error, flare) {
      if (error) throw error;

      root = flare;
      root.x0 = height / 2;
      root.y0 = 0;

      function collapse(d) {
        if (d.children) {
          d._children = d.children;
          d._children.forEach(collapse);
          d.children = null;
        }
      }

      root.children.forEach(collapse);
      update(root);
    });

    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

    function update(source) {

      // Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
          links = tree.links(nodes);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

      // Update the nodes…
      var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
          .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

      // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
          .on("click", click);

      nodeEnter.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 1e-6)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

      nodeEnter.append("text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Transition nodes to their new position.
      var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

      nodeUpdate.select("circle")
          .attr("r", 4.5)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

      nodeUpdate.select("text")
          .style("fill-opacity", 1);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
          .remove();

      nodeExit.select("circle")
          .attr("r", 1e-6);

      nodeExit.select("text")
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

      // Update the links…
      var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
          .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

      // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
      link.enter().insert("path", "g")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
          });

      // Transition links to their new position.
      link.transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", diagonal);

      // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
      link.exit().transition()
          .duration(duration)
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
            return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
          })
          .remove();

      // Stash the old positions for transition.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
      });
    }

    // Toggle children on click.
    function click(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
      update(d);
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
tree.sort(d3.ascending)
```

Do it like this:

```
var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]).sort(function(a,b){
      return a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase());
    });;
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xHZGQNvHe9yfRWAMFHGB?p=preview)

Comment: THANKS!!! If I don't care about case insensitivity, can I use `d3.ascending`? Can you show me how? I cannot find any examples of it being used.

Comment: For object sort you will need to give a sort function `d3.ascending` will not work. if you don't care about case insensitive do : `return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);`

Comment: Hi, is it possible to update your answer for d3 v4/v5? I realize that the sort function has changed in v4 onwards. It would be of great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your flare.json is similar with the example one you can use the js sort function to handle this.

```
if (error) throw error;

flare.children.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.name < b.name) return -1;
    if(a.name > b.name) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: I would prefer not modifying the underlying JSON structure. Isn't there a flag I can set on the tree that will just do this?

Comment: @SaqibAli according to the documentation https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout there is a sort function in tree that does this with ascending and descending features. So I'm guessing there is not a flag like you wanted. But if you want to keep the original JSON too why not bind this sorted one into a new object?

Comment: See my edit to the original question in which I answered your comment. Thank you.